# Specify template name from field value

Tags: django, django-views

Im trying to write a DetailView to use a field in the model called `template_name` where I could specify the template name on each entry (like the flatpages model). Im trying to use DetailView, but maybe I should not use it?

Here is what I have tried to write, but I get a this error: `'NoneType' object has no attribute 'render'`

```
class EntryDetailView(DetailView):
    
    model = Entry
       
    def get_template_names(Entry, **kwargs):
        if Entry.template_name:
            template_name = "entry/%s" % Entry.template_name
        else:
            template_name = "entry/entry_detail.html"
```

Any tips on how to get it right?

## Edit:

Here is mye traceback:

```
Traceback:
File "/home/USER/.virtualenvs/PROJECT/src/Django-1.6b2/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  139.                 response = response.render()
File "/home/USER/.virtualenvs/PROJECT/src/Django-1.6b2/django/template/response.py" in render
  105.             self.content = self.rendered_content
File "/home/USER/.virtualenvs/PROJECT/src/Django-1.6b2/django/template/response.py" in rendered_content
  82.         content = template.render(context)

Exception Type: AttributeError at /entries/test/
Exception Value: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'render'
```

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: can you show the entire stacktrace ?

Comment: First off, `get_template_names` should return a list of template locations. Second, it doesn't take any arguments. Take a look at [the source](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/views/generic/base.py#L135).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this (assuming Django 1.5):

```
class EntryDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Entry
    template_name_field = 'template_name'
```

Docs about [template_name_field](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/class-based-views/mixins-single-object/#django.views.generic.detail.SingleObjectTemplateResponseMixin.template_name_field).